# Symfony2: autoload/register namespaces from within a Bundle

Tags: symfony

I am working on a bundle in which I use the Doctrine CouchDB ODM. How does one autoload and register the namespaces from within a bundle? Here are the relevant working lines from `app/autoload.php` that I need to move:

```
use Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\UniversalClassLoader;

$loader->registerNamespaces(array(
    // ...
    'Doctrine\\CouchDB' => __DIR__.'/../vendor/doctrine-odm/lib',
    'Doctrine\\ODM\\CouchDB' => __DIR__.'/../vendor/doctrine-odm/lib',
));
```

Thank you!

Comment: Why exactly do you _need_ to move them?

Comment: You usually don't have to do it. Just put the declarations in your ```app/autoload.php``` and, if the bundle will be available to the public, add the info to your README.

Comment: The idea was to eliminate the need for folks implementing this bundle to add stuff to their `app`. @alessandro1997 implies that adding to `app/autoload.php` is the only way it's done, which would explain why I haven't found any instructions!

Comment: An interesting question, but I'd argue that it's better to keep namespace declarations in autoload.php to avoid possible duplicates if they were defined within the bundles directly. An unlikely scenario, but still possible, and would be annoying to debug :)

Comment: Composer is the tool that was developed to deal with this: http://knplabs.com/blog/symfony2-with-composer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Composer was added to address this issue:
http://knplabs.com/blog/symfony2-with-composer

Comment: The provided link no longer works. Can you please add/paste the relevant answer here?

Comment: Heh, this is a bit obsolete, as Composer has become the PHP community standard for dependency management, supplanting PEAR https://getcomposer.org/